# Setting/manipulating color and line color for SimpleFillSymbol

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to create a graphics layer over a designated area that has a background color and an opposing line color.  I read on the API Documentation that the `color` parameter only applies when `SimpleFillSymbol.style = "STYLE_SOLID"`.  Is there a way to set a color when `SimpleFillSymbol.style = "STYLE_FORWARD_DIAGONAL"`?

So with my current need I need the background to be yellow with lines running through it.

```
restricted_areas.symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_FORWARD_DIAGONAL, null, new Color([255, 255, 0]));
```

I simply get a background with lines but no color.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the color because the fill for SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_FORWARD_DIAGONAL is an image

If you're using the Arcgis JSAPI from arcgis.com then the image is located here.

http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/images/symbol/sfs/forwarddiagonal.png?version=4

So using SimpleFillSymbol with the STYLE_FORWARD_DIAGONAL style is really just a convenience function for a PictureFillSymbol with a specific picture.

To change and customize the color of the fill you'll have to use a [PictureFillSymbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/picturefillsymbol-amd.html) and then you can use whatever image and color you want.